# A monotone subadditive non-atomic $f$ on the power of $\bf N$ hasa partition $A,B$ s.t. $f(A),f(B) \in (0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

A real-valued function $f$ defined on the power set of $\mathbf{N}$ is said to be non-atomic whenever for all $X \subseteq \mathbf{N}$ such that $f(X)>0$, there exists $y \in (0,f(X))$ and $Y\subseteq X$ such that $f(Y)=y$.

**Question:** Let $f$ be a function such that non-atomic monotone subadditive function and such that $f(\mathbf{N})=1$. Does there exists a partition $\{A,B\}$ of $\mathbf{N}$ for which
$$
f(A) \in (0,1) \text{ and }f(B) \in (0,1)?
$$

---

To be precise, we say that $f$ is monotone if $f(X)\le f(Y)$ whenever $X\subseteq Y$ and subadditive if $f(X\cup Y) \le f(X)+f(Y)$ whenever $X,Y \subseteq \mathbf{N}$.

Even though it seems to be simple question, I am not really convinced of that.. You can find related questions, in a vague sense, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219274/reference-request-darboux-properties-of-real-valued-set-functions-measures-de) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404968/does-darboux-property-imply-strong-darboux-property).

Comment: It seems this is not true. I think if we use the notion of upper density $\bar{d}$ to define a function $f$ to be $f(A)=3\bar{d}(A)$ if $\bar{d}(A)\leq1/3$ and $1$ otherwise. This function seems to satisfy all the condition so it may be a counter example if I haven't made any mistake.

Comment: @SimingTu You are right! You may want to take a look here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/220268/does-a-monotone-subadditive-f-mathcalp-bf-n-to-0-1-admit-a-finite-part , which is what I really had in mind..